# Booster Water Pump for Intermittent (Input) Supply)

Tags: water-pressure, pump

We live in Mexico in a small village which has an intermittent water supply.  Our small neighborhood is on a hill, which means that when the water comes on at the street, the water tanks of the lowest homes fill first and fastest.  There is greater than a 30 foot rise between the street and the water tank at the top home, so that home fills last AND because the water pressure is very low, the tank takes forever to fill.
My idea was to have a booster pump at the street to improve water pressure and filling times for all the homes' tanks.

I should add that the pipe from the street is probably 3" in diameter...

THE QUESTION: Is there such a thing as a booster pump that has an intake switch which turns off when there is no pressure and turns on the pump when water pressure rises adequately (when the pueblo turns the water on)?????

Other thoughts welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Any pump will be limited by the inlet conditions - so creating a reservoir may be an idea.

Comment: I think that's how the booster pump works - increase line pressure when water is circulating, and shut off when no flow. The on and off are automatically controlled by a sensor (I guess). You shall call the vendors for information. Anticipate a huge pump though.

Comment: A reservoir as large as all the tanks in the upper neighborhood if you want to use a pump to accelerate the delivery of the water to the upper tanks.  A pump connected directly to the waterline will lack the input volume to make the pump effective.